# How to tracking down slow loading JS in IE8?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ie-developer-tools

One of the websites I work on loads extremely slow in IE8 and Im trying to track down the culprit. The website is virginwines.com

Anyone have any advice around how I can use browser tools to figure out which JS is causing the issue(s)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) - a debugging proxy - to view traffic between IE and the site. With IE8, the site is getting stalled on 8 images with a no-cache directive that are returning a 404.

```
#   Result  Protocol    Host    URL Body    Caching Content-Type    Process Comments    Custom  
9   404 HTTP    www.virginwines.com /images/us/en/brands/virgin/internet_explorer/borderTopLeft.png 1,529   no-cache  Expires: Wed, 08 Dec 2010 17:42:00 GMT    text/html;charset=UTF-8 iexplore:1784           
10  404 HTTP    www.virginwines.com /images/us/en/brands/virgin/internet_explorer/borderTopCenter.png   1,529   no-cache  Expires: Wed, 08 Dec 2010 17:42:01 GMT    text/html;charset=UTF-8 iexplore:1784           
11  404 HTTP    www.virginwines.com /images/us/en/brands/virgin/internet_explorer/borderTopRight.png    1,529   no-cache  Expires: Wed, 08 Dec 2010 17:42:01 GMT    text/html;charset=UTF-8 iexplore:1784           
12  404 HTTP    www.virginwines.com /images/us/en/brands/virgin/internet_explorer/borderMiddleLeft.png  1,529   no-cache  Expires: Wed, 08 Dec 2010 17:42:01 GMT    text/html;charset=UTF-8 iexplore:1784           
13  404 HTTP    www.virginwines.com /images/us/en/brands/virgin/internet_explorer/borderMiddleRight.png 1,529   no-cache  Expires: Wed, 08 Dec 2010 17:42:02 GMT    text/html;charset=UTF-8 iexplore:1784           
14  404 HTTP    www.virginwines.com /images/us/en/brands/virgin/internet_explorer/borderBottomLeft.png  1,529   no-cache  Expires: Wed, 08 Dec 2010 17:42:02 GMT    text/html;charset=UTF-8 iexplore:1784           
15  404 HTTP    www.virginwines.com /images/us/en/brands/virgin/internet_explorer/borderBottomCenter.png    1,529   no-cache  Expires: Wed, 08 Dec 2010 17:42:03 GMT    text/html;charset=UTF-8 iexplore:1784           
16  404 HTTP    www.virginwines.com /images/us/en/brands/virgin/internet_explorer/borderBottomRight.png 1,529   no-cache  Expires: Wed, 08 Dec 2010 17:42:03 GMT    text/html;charset=UTF-8 iexplore:1784
```

As mentioned by others, you can use the IE developer tool bar (F12) and [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite) is available for most major browsers. (If you're using FireFox, you should already be familiar with the full [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com).)

Comment: Awesome, that was a huge help. I added in the missing images and now the page is loading much faster!

Comment: Fiddler is an excellent tool to have in your arsenal. Sometimes just seeing the raw HTTP requests gives you insight that's difficult to get otherwise. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [Developer Tools Profiler](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/09/11/introducing-the-ie8-developer-tools-jscript-profiler.aspx) in IE8 to see where it is spending most of its time.

Comment: and +1 to you for the tool i did not know about :)